# Chrome store extension, which set from Public to private visibility options - How about updates?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have chrome store extension, which I have switch visiblity options from Public to Private. This means, that nobody can see this extension anymore. Only old users can use this extension. This is what I need.   I dont have any google groups but I still need to be able for old users who have already extension in their browsers, to get new updates, to keep extension up to date. Some fixes are always needed but I dont want to set it to public or unlisted.

If I set visilbity options in https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/edit/"extension" to PRIVATE visibility, will old users still get our updates?

Thanks for clarification and your help.

Comment: Anybody, please help